# Modify and recompile aes.c file in openwrt

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation, aes, openwrt, mikrotik

I'm trying to modify the AES implementation in the OpenWrt firmware build, specifically the aes.c file located in the directory ./build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt7621/linux-5.15.134/lib/crypto/aes.c. I've made some changes to the AES S-box, but when I try to compile the code using the following command:

```
SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
Copyright (C) 2017-2019 Linaro Ltd <ard.biesheuvel@linaro.org>

#include <crypto/aes.h>
#include <linux/crypto.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <asm/unaligned.h>

/*
 * Emit the sbox as volatile const to prevent the compiler from doing
 * constant folding on sbox references involving fixed indexes.
 */
static volatile const u8 __cacheline_aligned aes_sbox[] = {
        0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5,
        0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
        0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0,
        0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
        0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc,
        0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
        0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a,
        0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
        0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0,
        0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
        0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b,
        0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
        0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85,
        0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
        0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5,
        0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
        0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17,
        0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
        0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88,
        **0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,**

i change the higlighted values

Error:
root@shahzaib-System-Product-Name:/home/shahzaib/openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt7621/linux-5.15.134/lib/crypto# gcc -I./build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt7621/linux-5.15.134/include/crypto/aes.h -c aes.c -o aes.o
aes.c:6:10: fatal error: crypto/aes.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <crypto/aes.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I want to modify the es s-box of my linux kernel of openwrt but i got these errors.Kindly suggest me some authentic solution for this error.I'm not sure why the compiler can't find the aes.h file. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Try this `gcc -I./build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt7621/linux-5.15.134/include -c aes.c -o aes.o`